# Animation is slow in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a problem that when I render an animation on a canvas, the animation speed is decreasing until it is very slow.
I tried many things but I couldn't solve the problem.

I have two canvases, one where I play the animation and other canvas where delivery in three parts

```
my code is :  http://jsfiddle.net/TZLm2/
```

Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: A jsfiddle could be useful to try this out and help you furthermore

Comment: I solve the problem , I add beginPath(); and the animation is fast

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem , I add beginPath(); and the animation is fast!

source : [Redrawing HTML5 canvas incredibly slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150779/redrawing-html5-canvas-incredibly-slow)