# Canvas drawing is very slow

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to display scale with markings which is working fine. On top of that I also want to display mouse location in the scale with red indicator.

So, I draw canvas when I run the app and then I'm redrawing entire canvas when mouse location is changed.

I'm new to canvas and don't understand whats wrong in my code. I have been trying to resolve it but no luck.

Problem might be in this function,

```
 function drawBlackMarkers(y, coordinateMeasurment){
    const markHightY = scaleTextPadding.initial;
    ctxLeft.moveTo(coordinateMeasurment, y + markHightY);
    ctxLeft.lineTo(completeMarkHight, y + markHightY);
  }
```

I'm having a big **for loop** means so many iterations to go through and in that loop I call **drawBlackMarkers** function that many times as shown below.

```
function setMarkers(initialValY, rangeValY, coordinateMeasurmentr, divisableVal,
    scaleCountStartValueOfY, scaleCountRangeValueOfY) {
    let count = 0;
    // re-modifying scale staring and ending values based on zoom factor
    const scaleInceremnt = scaleIncementValue;
    for (let y = (initialValY), scaleCountY = scaleCountStartValueOfY;
      y <= (rangeValY) && scaleCountY <= scaleCountRangeValueOfY;
      y += scaleInceremnt, scaleCountY += incrementFactor) {


      switch (count) {
        case displayScale.starting:
          coordinateMeasurment = marktype.bigMark; count++;
          const scaleValY = scaleCountY - divisableVal;

          ctxLeft.strokeStyle = colors.black;

          ctxLeft.font = scaleNumberFont;
          const size = ctxLeft.measureText(scaleValY.toString());
          ctxLeft.save();
          const textX = coordinateMeasurment + ((size.width) / 2);
          const textY = y - scaleTextPadding.alignment;
          ctxLeft.translate(textX, textY);
          ctxLeft.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
          ctxLeft.translate(-textX, -textY);
          ctxLeft.fillText(scaleValY.toString(), coordinateMeasurment, y - scaleTextPadding.complete);
          ctxLeft.restore();
          break;
        case displayScale.middle:
          coordinateMeasurment = marktype.middleMark; count++;
          break;
        case displayScale.end:
          coordinateMeasurment = marktype.smallMark; count = 0;
          break;
        default:
          coordinateMeasurment = marktype.smallMark; count++;
          break;
      }

      // to draw scale lines on canvas
  // drawBlackMarkers(y, coordinateMeasurment);      
    }
  }
```

Please check this : http://jsfiddle.net/3v5nt7fe/1/

The problem is if I comment **drawBlackMarkers** function call, mouse co-ordinate updation is very fast but if I uncomment, it takes so long to update the location.

I really need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: For he best chance of getting some help you should add the function that has the problem `drawBlackMarkers`, not just the code that calls the function. We can not use code you have linked to (links are transient) and some, like me, simple cant be bothered to follow a link, we just move on to the next question.

Comment: @Blindman67 I completely agree. I update my question right now as per your comment.

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks for looking into it at least. Again, I completely agree with you. But the size is 64000  pixels that's because we have panning mechanism. It means you can scroll/pan the canvas (left, right, top, bottom) which is actually of 8000 px and on top of that we have zoom-in zoom-out functionalities which makes the canvas small and big and accordingly we have to change the markings on the ruler/scale. That's why it is a necessity to have size so big.  I can rethink on that part but it would require a lot of efforts to refactor it.

Comment: In demo-app I only display vertical scale but in my real app, we have horizontal ruler/scale implemented as well. Now the problem is, horizontal scales with the same size (64000) works without any delay but vertical scale takes time. It would be hard to believe but its the reality.

Comment: Look at google maps, it has a huge virtual map that can be zoomed in and out, panned, etc, yet the canvas never gets bigger than the device display res. Making the canvas too large will force the GPU to swap out RAM as it renders different parts of the canvas. Once you go over the RAM limit rendering even one pixel will be very slow. The simple fact is you can not have a canvas much larger than the display res and expect 60fps performance. BTW You are right on the edge of canvas max area see link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Usage_notes

Comment: @Blindman67. I have to re-look on what I can do. Thanks a ton for your input though.

Comment: If you're working on a map sort of thing, maybe just use Leaflet.js as your basis?

Comment: Your problem is because the canvas is huge. You're drawing things that are way off screen. Adding in the strokes from setBlackMarkers is only the final straw. On my newly new PC its taking nearly 1 second to draw the ruler.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the `drawBlackMarkers` itself, it's this:

```
for (let y = (initialValY), scaleCountY = scaleCountStartValueOfY;
  y <= (rangeValY) && scaleCountY <= scaleCountRangeValueOfY;
  y += scaleInceremnt, scaleCountY += incrementFactor) {
```

This is constantly increasing and happening 640,000 times. You can tell that's the case by writing:

```
  // to draw scale lines on canvas
  // drawBlackMarkers(y, coordinateMeasurment);
  console.log(y);
```

and seeing the console result.

So that for loop does very little, because most of it is behind a switch statement, and when it does even this simple `drawBlackMarkers` outside its showing the true cost of that loop. `rangeValY` is 640,000, which means the path the canvas context must construct is enormous.

So to fix this you must find a way to ameliorate that problem.

Comment: Yes I completely agree that it has many iterations but without `drawBlackMarkers`, it is fast because it doesn't draw 2D graphics on the canvas but with `drawBlackMarkers` it does. I'm working on it to reduce the iterations. Thanks a ton tough for your input.

Answer (score 1):

### This is doing a lot of unnecessary work

The screen is not 64000 pixels in height. You want to calculate the viewport, and only draw what is in the viewport.

Your function drawBlackMarkers is not the culprit. The system is very slow before that, its simply adding one more thing to be drawn. It was the straw that broke the camel's back.

By reducing the length of what you are drawing, you can very easily avoid the wasted CPU cycles.

In this version, all I have done is re-enable drawBlackMarkers, and shrink the canvas.

```js
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 2000;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 50;
const completeMarkHight = 15;
const divisibleValue = 0;
const scaleIncementValue = 10;
const scaleTextPadding = { initial: 0, middle: 5, end: 10, complete: 15, alignment: 18 };
const displayScale = { starting: 0, middle: 5, end: 9 };
const colors = { red: '#FF0000', white: '#D5D6D7', black: '#181c21' };
const marktype = { bigMark: 0, middleMark: 5, smallMark: 10 };
const startingInitialOrigin = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const scaleNumberFont = '10px Titillium Web Regular';
const defaultZoomLevel = 100;
const markingGap = {level1: 400, level2: 200, level3: 100, level4: 50, level5: 20, level6: 10 };
const zoomScaleLevel = {level0: 0, level1: 25, level2: 50, level3: 100, level4: 200, level5: 500, level6: 1000};



var $canvas = $('#canvas');
var ctxLeft = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
var mousePositionCoordinates;
var pagePositions = { x: 100, y:0 };
var  remainderX;
var  remainderY;
var  scaleCountRemainderX;
var  scaleCountRemainderY;
var  zoomFactor;
var  zoomScale;
var  zoomLevel;
var  multiplyFactor;
var  incrementFactor;
var  markingDistance;
var  timetaken=0;
ctxLeft.fillStyle = colors.white;

function render() {
    clear();
    ctxLeft.beginPath();
    zoomScale = 1000;
    zoomLevel = 1000;
    zoomFactor = zoomLevel / defaultZoomLevel;
    markingDistance = markingGap.level6;
    multiplyFactor = markingDistance / defaultZoomLevel;
    incrementFactor = markingDistance / scaleIncementValue; 

    renderVerticalRuler(startingInitialOrigin.y);
   
}

 function renderVerticalRuler(posY) {
     
    
    const initialValY = - posY / multiplyFactor;
    const rangeValY = (CANVAS_WIDTH - posY) / multiplyFactor;

    const initialValOfYwithMultiplyFactor = -posY;
    const rangeValOfYwithMultiplyFactor = (CANVAS_WIDTH - posY);


    // to adjust scale count get remainder value based on marking gap
    scaleCountRemainderY = initialValOfYwithMultiplyFactor % markingDistance;
    const scaleCountStartValueOfY = initialValOfYwithMultiplyFactor - scaleCountRemainderY;
    const scaleCountRangeValueOfY = rangeValOfYwithMultiplyFactor - scaleCountRemainderY;

    // to get orgin(0,0) values
    remainderY = initialValY % 100;
    const translateY = (posY / multiplyFactor) - remainderY;

    ctxLeft.translate(origin.x, translateY); // x,y
    const coordinateMeasurment = 0;

    const t0 = performance.now();
    setMarkers(initialValY, rangeValY, coordinateMeasurment, divisibleValue, scaleCountStartValueOfY, scaleCountRangeValueOfY);

    const t1 = performance.now()
    console.log("it took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");

    ctxLeft.stroke();
    ctxLeft.closePath();
  }
  
function setMarkers(initialValY, rangeValY, coordinateMeasurmentr, divisableVal,
    scaleCountStartValueOfY, scaleCountRangeValueOfY) {
    let count = 0;
    // re-modifying scale staring and ending values based on zoom factor
    const scaleInceremnt = scaleIncementValue;
    for (let y = (initialValY), scaleCountY = scaleCountStartValueOfY;
      y <= (rangeValY) && scaleCountY <= scaleCountRangeValueOfY;
      y += scaleInceremnt, scaleCountY += incrementFactor) {


      switch (count) {
        case displayScale.starting:
          coordinateMeasurment = marktype.bigMark; count++;
          const scaleValY = scaleCountY - divisableVal;

          ctxLeft.strokeStyle = colors.black;

          ctxLeft.font = scaleNumberFont;
          const size = ctxLeft.measureText(scaleValY.toString());
          ctxLeft.save();
          const textX = coordinateMeasurment + ((size.width) / 2);
          const textY = y - scaleTextPadding.alignment;
          ctxLeft.translate(textX, textY);
          ctxLeft.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
          ctxLeft.translate(-textX, -textY);
          ctxLeft.fillText(scaleValY.toString(), coordinateMeasurment, y - scaleTextPadding.complete);
          ctxLeft.restore();
          break;
        case displayScale.middle:
          coordinateMeasurment = marktype.middleMark; count++;
          break;
        case displayScale.end:
          coordinateMeasurment = marktype.smallMark; count = 0;
          break;
        default:
          coordinateMeasurment = marktype.smallMark; count++;
          break;
      }

      // to draw scale lines on canvas
   drawBlackMarkers(y, coordinateMeasurment);
    }
  }
  
  
 function drawBlackMarkers(y, coordinateMeasurment){
    const markHightY = scaleTextPadding.initial;
    ctxLeft.moveTo(coordinateMeasurment, y + markHightY);
    ctxLeft.lineTo(completeMarkHight, y + markHightY);
  }
  
  
function clear() {
    ctxLeft.resetTransform();
    ctxLeft.clearRect(origin.x, origin.y, CANVAS_HEIGHT, CANVAS_WIDTH);
}


render();
$('.canvas-container').mousemove(function(e) {
   
    
    mousePositionCoordinates = {x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY};
             
        render();
        
        // SHOW RED INDICATOR 
        ctxLeft.beginPath();
        ctxLeft.strokeStyle = colors.red;  // show mouse indicator
        ctxLeft.lineWidth = 2;

        // to display purple indicator based on zoom level
        const mouseX = mousePositionCoordinates.x * zoomFactor;
        const mouseY = mousePositionCoordinates.y * zoomFactor;
        const markHightY =scaleTextPadding.initial + this.remainderY;
        ctxLeft.moveTo(marktype.bigMark, e.clientY );
        ctxLeft.lineTo(completeMarkHight, e.clientY);
        ctxLeft.stroke();
        $('.mouselocation').text(`${mousePositionCoordinates.x},${mousePositionCoordinates.y}`);
   
});
```

```css
body, html{
  width: 100000px;
  height:100000px;
}
.canvas-container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.canvasLeft {
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid black;
    background: grey;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 1;
    top:0
}


.mouselocation{
  position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="canvasLeft" width="30" height="2000"></canvas>
</div>


<div class="mouselocation">
   
</div>
```